# Android, Context menu button in listitem

Tags: android, contextmenu

I am looking at the moment at the google music app. And I really like the menu button approach they add to the gridview items.

My question is, is there some sort of third party open source library or code snippet i could use to get this effect?

Check the image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope it's a simple `ImageButton` they add, and they use the overflow icon as the src.

So basically, all you need is to download the overflow icon from somewhere, add an image button to your grid item layout and then add some code to your custom adapter's getView to handle the clicks.

Comment: Thanks, Managed to get it working. Trying to make the code reusable and throw it on Github since i believe more people would like this.